# What's the best way to authenticate and authorize a web and api solution like MERN Stack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm trying to find the best way to implement authorization. At this time, only thing I need is a simple free account, but later I may include user roles for a "premium" account using a payment system like stripe.

I have already started reading and experimenting with Auth0 but then found some other ways I can do it.

1. Passport.js + MongoDB, I've seen some examples and work great but I think it is missing a way to control users, rules etc with a friendly panel (like Auth0)
2. Using Auth0 and setting up a custom database (mongoDB). Also seems to be behind a paywall.
3. Also found a way to use both Auth0 for authentication and Mongoose for a MongoDB database. In this one, everything is saved in mongoDB except passwords. It's also the only setup that deleting a user from Auth0 is not affecting the MongoDB (which is bad I guess).

So, some questions are

1. which method you think is better?
2. What is the difference between 2 and 3,
3. Is there a way to implement rules in passport (e.g. redirect new users on first login)
4. If I implement Passport with MongoDB, and my database has hundreds of users, how can I manage them?

A bit of a chaos question but any help would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best authorization strategy depends of the scope of your applications in a short or long term.

## Monolithic or simple web with Private login

For example, if you will have just a simple(MERN) web with a one simple backend (api rest) or a monolithic application like this [mern example](https://github.com/harryworld/mern-helloworld) with an internal or private login in your organization, your authorization strategy could be as simple as :

- (1*) /login express route which receive user/password, validate them in database and returns the clasic jwt token and an array of options (react routes) to which the user should have access
- web app (react) must render pages whose routes match with the received routes
- web app must send the received token to any api rest endpoint invocation
- when api receive the invocation from react web, must validate the existence of token as a header. If not exist, must return a 403 error.
- (2*) If token exist, must try to validate it (well-formed, not expired, correct signature, etc).
- (3*)If its is a valid token, you must perform a last validation: Is user with "guest" role allowed to execute a `DELETE` to an endpoint `/user/100`.
- (4*) Classic solution is to have some tables in your database like: user, roles, user_roles, role_permission, permission_option. Option table must have registered all your api endpoints and its method. Also this could be used to create the relation between user <:> web routes. Check [this](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/2b50e9071de6d815aa2647914fead7d9)

## Modern requirements

Modern and large organizations require:

- Social Network Logins
- Internal/External Users
- Not interactive logins (robots, schedulers, etc)
- Several web apps
- Several Mobile apps
- A lot of Api Rest

For this case, MERN app is not a good choice because is ALL-IN-ONE. Common strategy to implement the previous requirements is to have several artifacts deployed in several servers:

- web app (react, vue, angular, linkstart, etc)
- apis rest (nodejs + expres, java, python, etc)
- authentication/authorization: oauth2 platform/provider, Identity/Access Platforms, etc

If this is your case, you must split your MERN app into several deployable artifacts: web, api and security.

## Oauth2

No matter if you are concern just for login or how ensure the authentication and authorization for your webs, apis and maybe your mobile apps, you will need : OAUTH2

You could develop your own security platform taking into consideration (1*), (2*), (3*) y (4*) or use something like:

- auth0
- keycloack, etc

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62049409

## Your questions

- which method you think is better?

  - I think if you will use auth0, you will save time and effort. With auth0 you just need a simple express app, with some endpoints like /login, /callback, etc. Or if you use auth0 + passport.js, these endpoints are managed by passport.js
  - I advice you , review how OAUTH2 flow works before to use auth0 with/without passport. This [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) helped me a lot.
- What is the difference between 2 and 3,

  - As I read, auth0 and another platforms offer a user management service or it can connect to your users service (AD/LDAP, database, api, etc). So
- Is there a way to implement rules in passport (e.g. redirect new users on first login)

  - Yes. You can add some logic when callback is redirected in your nodejs with or without passport.
- If I implement Passport with MongoDB, and my database has hundreds of users, how can I manage them?

  - Nowadays database support a lot of rows. So for your production database try to optimize or monitor it. Another option is to hire a database administrator to perform these tasks.

## References

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2
- https://auth0.com/user-management
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62049409
- https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/roles-permissions/index.html
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36935/best-relational-database-structure-for-this-data
- https://www.mind-it.info/2010/01/09/nist-rbac-data-model/
- [Managing single sign on using passportjs for my own web applications - sharing login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61940910/managing-single-sign-on-using-passportjs-for-my-own-web-applications-sharing-l/62049409#62049409)
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/how-to-integrate-rest-apis-with-single-page-apps-and-secure-them-using-auth0-part-1/
- [Facebook OAuth security using passport-facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844290/facebook-oauth-security-using-passport-facebook#comment109452822_61844290)
- [Asynchronous Django, Ajax, Jquery Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838998/asynchronous-django-ajax-jquery-information/61883353#61883353)
- [relational models](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/2b50e9071de6d815aa2647914fead7d9)

Comment: Woah! Thanks you for the answer JRichardsz! So, as far as I understand using a service like auth0 ensures I'll avoid the security headache in the long term. As far as the free limits are ok (I see like 7k users). Now, I currently use the MERN stack for user authentication and not making calls to the api. The api is a separate python api. So as I understand i should stick with that and not rewrite it in express.js, in case I make a mobile app in the future.. and use a auth0 token to give access to the api. One last thing I haven't figure out is if auth0 is enough or if a mongo db is needed too.

Comment: You are right related to your python api. Related to the database, with auth0 you don't need classic tables like user, user_role, etc. Maybe in this sprint you could start just with express + passport + auth0 + express-in-memory database. And in the next spring use redis as database for your express-sessions. if this was useful and/or was the solution to your problem, please give my like :D